# Typescript from command-line with file input, does not work with spaces in path

Tags: file, powershell, command-line, typescript

I have a PowerShell script that works like this:

1. Iterate through Path
2. Find all TypeScript files in this Path
3. Write the paths of these files in temp.txt
4. Call TypeScript compiler via command-line --> tsc, with the temp.txt as input

The TypeScript Version that is installed is 1.4.

It looks like this:

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot
$fileName = "temp.txt"
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ABC\main\DEF" -Include *.ts -Exclude jasmine -Recurse | foreach {$_.FullName | Out-File -filePath $fileName -Append}
tsc @$fileName --module amd
```

The script works, as long as the path which is iterated through does not contain blank spaces.
In my case the path does contain blank spaces (see: ..\Visual Studio 2013...) And because of that the paths of the typescript files in the temp.txt also contain blank spaces.

Is there a possibility to write the paths in temp.txt so that the typescript compiler can actually resolve them, even though they contain blank spaces?

Moving the project is not the desired option.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like adding quotes to the

```
$_.Fullname
```

does the trick.

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot 
$fileName = "temp.txt"
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ABC\main\DEF" -Include *.ts -Exclude jasmine  -Recurse | foreach {'"'$_.FullName'"' | Out-File -filePath $fileName -Append}
tsc @$fileName --module amd
```